# iOS app submission: App is not signed

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, xcode5

I've been trying to submit my app for the past 24 hours to no avail. The problem has been caused mainly due to third-party frameworks I think. Especially the GooglePlus API. When I upgraded the GooglePlus API to its latest, the validation process gave me warnings about references made to non-public APIs, which I found impossible to fix, so I reverted to the previous version which hadn't given me any problems so far during submission.

Now when I did try to submit it again, it gives me the following error:

```
This bundle is invalid. The app is not signed.
```

I have no idea why. I signed it with the same provisioning profile I've been using for the previous versions. Any idea why this may be happening?

Comment: Do you put a folder with 'Create folder references for...' in the project?

Comment: No. Whenever I drag files into the project, I leave this option unchecked.

Comment: too little info. . post the relevant build settings AND run the code sign tool on the app to verify the sig: Terminal: `code sign -vvv %PATH_TO_APP%

Comment: I fixed the issue by removing the google-ios-sdk.